# Partner Community FULL vs Login license?

Tags: community, licenses, experience-cloud

I want to ensure I understand the different types of licenses. My use case is: Need to begin leveraging all the Partner Community Login licenses our company already has, and as of now we are only using the FULL Partner Community licenses. Is it fair to assume that we could just create a NEW custom profile (that uses the Login license) and basically clone the full profile we already use for partners on the FULL license?

Are there any limitations I would run into by basically duplicating the profile? Object/Field perms? Can user with a Login license still have permission sets and an account Role as the regular members do?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_migrate_users_between_licenses.htm&type=5